# Accessing SQL through SSH Tunnel

Tags: mysql, sql, localhost

hey guys so I'm having this weird error.
So I've created a tunnel from a remote computer onto mine.
SQL runs on the remove PC on port 3306
My tunnel config goes

ssh -N -L 33307:127.0.0.1:3306 something.something.com

This means that effectively traffic from port 3306 of remote pc is being directed to my 33307 127.0.0.1 port of my Mac. 
Now the problem is

mysql -u user -phfkahfkz -p 33307

DOES NOT work, gives a user@localhost error

mysql -u user -phfkahfkz -p 33307 -h 127.0.0.1 works fine

my host file already had

127.0.0.1 localhost

I tried adding

localhost 127.0.0.1

I'm clueless as to whats happening

Another question, so when I effectively create a tunnel, I don't need sql to be install on my Mac right? I though that it might be trying to connect to my local copy of sql so I stopped SQL from running locally and

mysql -u user -phfkahfkz -p 33307

mysql -u user -phfkahfkz -p 33307 -h localhost

both give a  Can't connect to local MySQL server

mysql -u user -phfkahfkz -p 33307 -h 127.0.0.1

works fine with local sql service stopped

Comment: FYI you have sql-server tagged in your post, but your examples are referencing MySql.

Comment: yup sorry my bad! thanks

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, localhost is different from 127.0.0.1.

Localhost is treated specially, meaning it does not use TCP/IP at all, but tries to communicate with a local instance of MySQL via a socket file.

You'll have to use 127.0.0.1 explicitly.

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html for details.